# Explain a performance difference

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

Here's the [Full Source](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/datafactory/src/288e395f376facabec63f2ec003337b1032f6362/src/test/java/com/xenoterracide/datafactory/RandomStringFactoryTest.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [a direct link to the data](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/datafactory/raw/288e395f376facabec63f2ec003337b1032f6362/src/main/resources/dictionary)

These tests have wildly varying timings but go through the same implementation. I'd like to understand why the timings are different.

```
private static final int ITERATIONS = 100;
private static final DataFactory RANDOM_DF = DataFactoryImpl.defaultInstance();


@Test // 6s
public void testGetMaxLength() throws Exception {
    for ( int i = 1; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) {
        testGetMaxLength( i );
    }
}

private void testGetMaxLength( final int length ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) {
        String word = RANDOM_DF.word().getMaxLength( length );
        assertThat( word, not( isEmptyOrNullString() ) );
        assertThat( word.length(), allOf( greaterThanOrEqualTo( 1 ), lessThanOrEqualTo( length ) ) );
    }
}

@Test //  301ms
public void testGetLength() throws Exception {
    for ( int i = 1; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) {
        testGetLength( i );
    }
}

private void testGetLength( final int length ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) {
        String word = RANDOM_DF.word().getLength( length );
        assertThat( word, not( isEmptyOrNullString() ) );
        assertThat( word.length(), equalTo( length ) );
```

This is the class `DataFactoryUtil` that most likely contains the code causing the massive difference.

```
final class DataFactoryUtil {
    private DataFactoryUtil() {
    }

    static <T> Optional<T> valueFromMap(
            final Map<Integer, List<T>> map,
            final IntUnaryOperator randomSupplier,
            final int minInclusive,
            final int maxInclusive
    ) {
        List<T> list = map.entrySet()
                .parallelStream() // line 26
                .filter( e -> e.getKey() >= minInclusive && e.getKey() <= maxInclusive )
                .map( Map.Entry::getValue )
                .flatMap( Collection::stream )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );

        return valueFromList( list, randomSupplier );
    }

    static <T> Optional<T> valueFromList( final List<T> list, final IntUnaryOperator randomSupplier ) {
    int random = randomSupplier.applyAsInt( list.size() );
    return list.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of( list.get( random ) );
    }

    static List<String> dict() {
        try {
            URL url = DataFactoryUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "dictionary" );
            assert url != null;
            return Files.lines( Paths.get( url.toURI() ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
        }
        catch ( URISyntaxException | IOException e ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException( e );
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the different implementations

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RandomStringFactory {

    default String getMaxLength( final int maxInclusive ) {
        return this.getRange( 1, maxInclusive );
    }

    String getRange( final int minInclusive, final int maxInclusive );

    default String getLength( int length ) {
        return this.getRange( length, length );
    }
}
```

and the actual implementation of `word`

```
DataFactoryImpl( final IntBinaryOperator randomSource, final List<String> wordSource ) {
    this.random = randomSource;
    this.wordSource = wordSource.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy( String::length ) );
}

public static DataFactory defaultInstance() {
    return new DataFactoryImpl( RandomUtils::nextInt, dict() );
}

default RandomStringFactory word() {
    return ( min, max ) -> valueFromMap( getWordSource(), ( size ) -> getRandom().applyAsInt( 0, size ), min, max )
            .orElse( alphabetic().getRange( min, max ) );


}
```

Why is the measurement of these 2 methods so different when they share an implementation? is there any way I can improve the worst case for `getMaxLength`?

**update**

while I like the theory of Random being the source, and maybe it's true. changing my code to this caused a `13s` run, which is longer than the run, which is more than twice the time of `RandomUtils::nextInt`.

```
public static DataFactory defaultInstance() {
    return new DataFactoryImpl( (a, b) -> a == b ? a :    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(a, b), dict() ); 
}
```

Comment: How have you performed these measurements? Did you apply the same warm-up period to both? Does the performane change if you swap their order? My assumption is JIT occurs between the first and second.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch just running them with Intellij, I haven't tried swapping them, I suppose I could

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if I run them independently the measurements are more like `5s`  `900ms` both using `parallelStream()` there is of course some variance between the numbers but it's still ranging at 5x the time.

Comment: Could it be that the overhead spawning and synching all the threads for `parralelStream()` takes sufficient time on the shorter test to make it run slower but is well amortized by the time the longer test finishes?

Comment: Are you asking why the time is different between the stream vs parallelStream implementations or why the time is different between the two tests? It's also simpler to follow this if you make one of these http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Tim no because as I just mentioned to tim the measurements come out similarly if I run each test method by itself.

Comment: @pvg after reflecting on it, I'm mostly interested in why one is taking ~5s to run and the other takes less than 1s. So I've removed notes about `parralelStream()` because that's obviously just increasing on one end due to thread synchronization.

Comment: @xenoterracide given that the only difference seems to be the calls getLength and getMaxLength, that seems like the obvious place to look. Unfortunately you haven't provided them.

Comment: @pvg I did, there's a link to bitbucket, they aren't very interesting, but I've pasted their implementation here for your pleasure

Comment: @pvg `word()` returns a lambda, it's a functional interface the thing it returns is `getRange`

Comment: Yeah I can see that but it's extremely difficult to follow with all the levels of indirection. Essentially, you seem to be asking why getRange(1,something) is slower than getRange(something,something). Could it it because the filter tosses out a lot of things in the latter case? Impossible to tell, we don't have your data and your code is huge and highly indirect.

Comment: @pvg according to cloc isn't even 300 lines. Yes it is *highly indirect*, and contains several abstractions so that it's easy to replace and write new pieces, there are several methods like `word` that aren't. I've added a direct link to the data, which would not be good to paste here, but it is in the bitbucket repo. The data is a copy of a cracklib dict.

Comment: @xenoterracide again, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
In fact, I bet if you wrote one you'd very quickly see where the performance difference comes from.

Comment: Seems that I understand what's your problem, but in general @pvg is right: you should simplify your code as much as possible before posting to SO. Often during the simplification you may understand what's the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is actually in [`RandomUtils.nextInt()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.java#84) implementation which you are using to produce random numbers. In case if `startInclusive` and `endInclusive` parameters match (like in `getLength()`), it just returns the argument which is really fast. Otherwise it requests static instance of `java.util.Random` object to get the random number. The `java.util.Random` is thread-safe, but has very serious contention problems: you cannot just independently request random numbers from different threads: they will starve in CAS-loops. As you are using `.parallelStream()` in your `valueFromMap`, you hit these problems.

The simplest fix to apply here is to use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) instead:

```
new DataFactoryImpl( (a, b) -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(a, b+1), dict() );
```

Note that `ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt()` has no fast-path like `RandomUtils.nextInt()`, so if you want to keep it, use:

```
new DataFactoryImpl( 
    (a, b) -> a == b ? a : ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(a, b+1), dict() );
```

Be careful not to cache `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` instance somewhere outside (like in field or static variable): this call must be performed in the same thread where random number is actually requested.

Comment: so I replaced the implemetnation of `defaultInstance` with yours minus 1 difference `nextInt( a, b )` instead of `b+1` because that was causing a random out of bounds when requesting a value from the List. this implementation takes `13s`... `public static DataFactory defaultInstance() {
        return new DataFactoryImpl(
                (a, b) -> a == b ? a : ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(a, b),
                dict() );
    }`

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the measurement of these 2 methods so different when they share
>   an implementation?

Well, consider you have a "shared implementation" for counting pages in a set of books.

In the first case the set consists of a single book. You open the last page, look at its number and - that's it! A piece of cake.

In the second case the given set of books is the National Library... Does the analogy help?

---

The same is in your test. `testGetLength` chooses a random word with the given length, where all words are already grouped by their lengths.

`filter( e -> e.getKey() >= minInclusive && e.getKey() <= maxInclusive )` retains at most one group of words, but more often, even zero (there are no words with length > 30).

`testGetMaxLength` chooses a random word shorter than the given length. The list of such words is never empty. Even worse, your `flatMap + collect` merges all by-length lists in one reeeeally large combined list, and this operation is reeeeally slow. Have you ever tried to use a profiler?

> is there any way I can improve the worst case for getMaxLength?

Of course. But this would require complete redesign of the algorithms and the data structures used. For example, you could sort all your dictionary by the word lengths, and then build an array-backed index that maps a length to the last position in the result list of a word of this length. In such case you'll be able to get a range (1, maxLength) in a constant time.

Comment: actually been looking for a good profiler for this kind of problem that integrated well with Intellij Idea, since this. This is one of the few performance problems I've hit where I think a profiler is more required (problem is relative since real usage is not intended to be 1000 times in a loop)